# Apply CSS style only to the loaded image from`<picture>` element

Tags: html, css, image, lighthouse

Lighthouse suggests [using next-gen image formats for faster download and less data consumption](https://web.dev/uses-webp-images/). And this is done using HTML `<picture>` element.

So when we use `<picture>` element, how to target CSS style only to the loaded image?

In the snippet below, you can see that the border gets added to other elements as well.

```css
picture * {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div style=" display: flex; gap: 30px; ">
  <p>AVIF: 50</p>
  <p>WebP: 100</p>
  <p>img: 150</p>
</div>

<picture>
  <source type="image/avif" srcSet="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="50" height="50" />
  <source type="image/webp" srcSet="https://via.placeholder.com/100" width="100" height="100" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</picture>
```

**Note**: at the time of this writing, Chrome supports AVIF, Edge & Firefox support WebP, so the respective file type gets loaded based on your browser.

[Screenshot of above snippet result taken from Microsoft Edge for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMD4u.png):

[image: HTML picture element styling]

Comment: picture img{...} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loaded image will be represented by the `img` Tag so you can just target that element.

The different source elements just provide different sources (therefore its called that way) but the browser decided what to use (by different factors) and load it into the img tag.

You can either target it by the tag name (`picture img`) or add an actual css class (which i would recommend like `picture .image` - see snippet).

```css
picture .image {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div style=" display: flex; gap: 30px; ">
  <p>AVIF: 50</p>
  <p>WebP: 100</p>
  <p>img: 150</p>
</div>

<picture>
  <source type="image/avif" srcSet="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="50" height="50" />
  <source type="image/webp" srcSet="https://via.placeholder.com/100" width="100" height="100" />
  <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</picture>
```

Comment: just for reference - it's mentioned in [Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture#:~:text=The%20selected%20image%20is%20then%20presented%20in%20the%20space%20occupied%20by%20the%20%3Cimg%3E%20element.)

Answer (score 1):

The style selector only needs to target the img tag inside the picture element. Instead of picture * you can try doing picture img.

However, it would be recommendable to add a class to the img tag inside the picture element and target this in your CSS for best practice.